# Displaying output to a UILabel from UIPickerView using a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uipickerview

Im working on a Countries and Capitals app as part of an Objective-C Course.

So far when the user selects a Country in the picker the relevent Capital City is displayed in the label below.

My question is how can I code it so the Capital City is displayed only after the user clicks the "Get Capital" button.

I know this seems less efficient but it would be useful to know how!

[SIMULATOR PIC](http://hostmypicture.com/images/1wjw.jpg)

```
countryNames =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"England",
                                              @"United States",
                                              @"India",
                                              @"Australia",
                                              @"Canada",
                                              @"France",
                                              @"The Netherlands",
                                              @"South Africa",nil];
cityNames =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"London",
                                           @"Washington DC",
                                           @"Dehli",
                                           @"Canberra",
                                           @"Ottawa",
                                           @"Paris",
                                           @"Amsterdam",
                                           @"Cape Town",nil];
```

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

```
lblcapitalCity.text =[cityNames objectAtIndex:row];
```

}

// Not sure after doing this how to only display cities after a button is clicked

Comment: Don't do anything in didSelectRow.  Create a button and attach an action to it that assigns lblCapitalCity.text based on `[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]`

Comment: Thanks @David but I still don't understand after reading your solution. What changes should I make to:
    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

and what should I code here:

    - (IBAction)getCapitalButton:(id)sender {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate your `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` completely and use this action for the button:

```
-(IBAction)getCapitalButton:(id)sender
{
    lblCapitalCity.text = cityNames[[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
}
```